# ocupload module functionality

Tags: wysiwyg

I have installed the [ocupload module](https://drupal.org/project/ocupload) and works very well at my localhost enviroment.

But the problem appears to me when i deployed to the testing enviroment  the upload failed ant the alert message says error 200 - 401.

I walked throw the installation steps well and give the permissions for files .

I know it isn't a module bug but i need help to fix it or catch where the error comes from (running nginx with authentication required by the web server).

thanks in advance

Comment: Any chance you could provide error message screenshot and screenshots of target directories seen in sFTP software? Also, is normal file uploading unaffected?

Answer (score 0):

It solved by :

1- give the right permissions for the images folder (where the uploaded images).

2- disable the web server authentication.

hint (if you use ckeditor add the tag img to the text format)